FFMPEG only streaming one frame when capturing an application
I am streaming video captured from Device A to Device B. When I stream the entire captured desktop using ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 25 -i desktop -vcodec mpeg4 -q 12 -f mpegts "udp://[DEVICE_B_IP]:50" on Device A, it works fine. I can play the streamed video with ffplay -f mpegts udp:://127.0.0.1:50 on Device B.
However, when I chance the capture from the entire desktop to just the area of one application, changing -i desktop to -i title="ApplicationName", the video doesn't stream appropriately. ffplay -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:50 will display a single frame, although it will show the cursor from Device A moving around on the frozen frame displayed on Device B if it's moved.
Edit for clarification: I am streaming video from Device A to Device B, but when I stream just an application, it shows only one repeated frame rather than streaming the video properly. How do I make Device A stream the captured video correctly?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is the app window being moved or resized?

@Gyan the app window should not be moved or resized at all, and in this case hasn't been.

As long as the window stays in that desktop location, you can use this script. It lets you choose the area of desktop to capture.  Click top left corner, then bottom right corner.  That's the area that will capture.
It should still use display in the same manner with your chosen area.
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Click X coordinate (top left)\n"
    xdotool selectwindow &>/dev/null
x1=$(xdotool getmouselocation | awk '{print $1}')
y1=$(xdotool getmouselocation | awk '{print $2}')
echo -e "Click Y coordinate (bottom right)\n"
    xdotool selectwindow &>/dev/null
x2=$(xdotool getmouselocation | awk '{print $1}')
y2=$(xdotool getmouselocation | awk '{print $2}')

x1_coord=$(echo "${x1/*x:/}")
y1_coord=$(echo "${y1/*y:/}")
x2_coord=$(echo "${x2/*x:/}")
y2_coord=$(echo "${y2/*y:/}")

width=$((x2_coord - x1_coord))
height=$((y2_coord - y1_coord))

screen_width=$(xdotool getdisplaygeometry | awk '{print $1}')
screen_height=$(xdotool getdisplaygeometry | awk '{print $2}')

crop_params="crop=$width:$height:$x1_coord:$y1_coord"

ffmpeg -hide_banner -f pulse -i default -f x11grab -i "$DISPLAY" -preset ultrafast -vf "$crop_params" -c:a copy -c:v mpeg4 -q 12 -f mpegts "udp://[DEVICE_B_IP]:50"

exit 0

Save as: record_area.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x record_area.sh
Run: ./record_area.sh

If it's still giving you issues, you can try a pipe.
Switch out the ffmpeg line in the script for the following block:
pipe_id=$(tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9_-' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 6 | head -n 1)
mkfifo "$pipe_id"

ffmpeg -hide_banner -f pulse -i default -f x11grab -i "$DISPLAY" -preset ultrafast -vf "$crop_params" -c:a copy -c:v mpeg4 -q 12 -f mpegts "$pipe_id" 2>/dev/null && rm "$pipe_id"

You should be able to connect directly to the pipe.
ffplay -f mpegts udp://192.168.0.x/[pipe id here]

If it's not going to move, hard code the coordinates instead. Type xdotool getmouselocation into a terminal.  Place your cursor to first location and press enter on the terminal.  There's the coordinate for x,y #1.  Repeat for bottom left, that's x,y #2.
Replace the x1,y1,x2,y2 in the script's lines below:
x1_coord=$(echo "${x1/*x:/}")
y1_coord=$(echo "${y1/*y:/}")
x2_coord=$(echo "${x2/*x:/}")
y2_coord=$(echo "${y2/*y:/}")

No more need to select the area.

Although the window isn't being moved, the command is going to be kicked off from a separate application. The end user should not need to select the display area each time.

@this_is_a_display_name I've added info on how to solve the need for selection.
